# iOS Local Push Notification Override Mute/Silent Mode

Tags: ios, notifications, push, local, silent

I am currently working on an iOS project that requires me to send a local push notification to a user with a sound. The issue is that I want the sound to play even if the device is muted or in silent mode, but I am not sure if this is possible.

There have been a few similar questions but none of them have been answered successfully like this: [iPhone - Is it possible to override silent mode or have a recursive alert sound with push notification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1917131/iphone-is-it-possible-to-override-silent-mode-or-have-a-recursive-alert-sound)

Disclaimer: I understand this is not a desirable feature for an app and that it might be cause for rejection from the App Store.

Comment: Do you have any luck with this question yet? I'm looking for the solution as well.

Comment: No I have not, and I think it's more or less impossible.

Answer (score 2):

I just found this question while searching something related to push notification..

You can achieve it by listening to the push notification and start playing a sound within your app when receiving the push notification

1) for iOS7 and above, you can get the push notification even user doesn't open the app by using this method

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult result))completionHandler;
```

2) inside the method, you can let your app to start playing a sound file. You may need a bit extra work to configure your AVAudioSession to allow your sound to play even when the device is in silent mode. you can check the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/AVFoundation/Reference/AVAudioSession_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html) for more details - it's gonna take some time to appropriately handle the audio.. you have to consider situations where other app is already playing sound or sound output from different channel e.g. speaker, earphones etc.

Comment: This unfortunately does not work when the user has force-closed the app, by sliding it up from the app switcher. The method is not called.

Comment: This is an interesting approach and the best available option for this sort of behavior imho, even if it doesn't exactly match the behavior asked for in the original quesiton.